# Facebook like not liking the proper page

Tags: c#, facebook, facebook-like

I have used the `<iframe>` like button of facebook to like my page, but the problem i'm facing here is that the like.php page of facebook ignores a part of my query string. For eg:

```
<iframe src="//www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href=http://stg.radioworld.com/default.aspx?tabid=75&amp;entryid=10220&amp;width=450&amp;height=21&amp;colorscheme=light&amp;layout=button_count&amp;action=like&amp;show_faces=false&amp;send=false&amp;appId=235245186502970" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="border: none; overflow: hidden; width: 93px; height: 28px; vertical-align: middle;" allowtransparency="true"></iframe>
```

Here, like.php ignores the `entryid` query string and always like `http://stg.radioworld.com/default.aspx?tabid=75`. Please help.

Comment: Have you tried sending the string without encoding the seperators?  (lost the &amp; and just use &).

Comment: @durbnpoisn still the same issue, if i use & instead of &amp; the page converts & to amp;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the issue is that the entire URL is not encoded. Since you are using .NET, you should be able to use [`UrlEncode`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httputility.urlencode.aspx) to correctly encode the entire parameter.

From the looks of it, your `?` and `:` in your sub URL are possibly causing issues.

Your URL should probably look something like this:

```
"...like.php?href=http%3A//stg.radioworld.com/default.aspx%3Ftabid=75&amp;entryid=10220..."
```